# How to create a Date TEXTBOX in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, date, textbox, repeater

I am filling the repeater as follows:
Each line has a checkbox, some text and SHOULD have a date - textbox.
When a specific checkbox is checked ( if (cb.checked).. ) I would like to be able to edit the date - textbox for that specific row. 
The selected row will then be saved in a new datatable for further use.

My main problem is to find an elegant method that defines a DATE - TEXTBOX as an object in order to insert it somehow into each row in the repeater.
I know that I can insert an `<asp: textbox .. >` as a column just how to make it a date - textbox

Your help'd be appreciated.

p.s.
Since I am a noob, maybe an example might be more useful :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for a DateTimePicker?

Comment: I realize that this control enables selecting time as well. I need to select just the date. I am not sure if this is good for me since I never heard of it (yet). I need to have an option of adding a date to a selected row (the row is selected by the checkbox)

Comment: Look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47474/ASP-NET-Control-from-jQuery-DatePicker-in-3-Minute

Comment: Do you use jQuery and jQuery-UI in project?

Comment: Thank you Amiram but this wasn't so clear. Can't I just add a textbox and define something it its properties in order to avoid Json? Or even better, **can't I build a user control of such manner?**

Comment: boruchsiper I havent looked into it yet.. but I will. Thanks

Comment: Yuriy, as a matter of fact I don't but it seems that I don't have much choice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQueryUI datepicker
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

on your aspx page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#<%= YorDateTextBoxID.ClientID %>" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a fancy UI (such as a drop-down calendar or date part separators in the TextBox) you might be able to get by with a regular text box and a CompareValidator.

```
<asp:TextBox id="date1" runat="server" />
<asp:CompareValidator ControlToValidate="date1" Type="Date" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Must be a date" runat="server" />
```

This will not provide guidance or hints to your users, but it will force them to enter a date in order to submit.

Comment: The compare validator is too primitive for my project. I will try something that _boruchsiper_ suggested